# push a bunch of items to the server

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I get the error `TypeError: Object(...)(...).subscribe is not a function` if I run the following code.

```
push(models: Model[]): void {
    from(models).pipe(
                     mergeMap((m: Model) => this.service.push(m)),
                     bufferCount(models.length)
                ).subscribe(() => log('done'));
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to push each model to the server in parallel. And when all pushes are completed, I log a message.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to call push service and subscribe the response on every call is done?

Comment: you could at least add the signatures of the service methods...

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simplified code which does what you want.

The important bit is the push method in the service. Obviously, you will need to change it to match the HTTP request you are making. The `console.log` statement in `ngOnInit` logs a list of all server responses **after all** responses have completed.

.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { PushItService } from './push-it.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public myObservable$

  constructor(private pushItService: PushItService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myObservable$ = this.pushItService.push([{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}])
    this.myObservable$.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('data', data)
    })
  }
}
```

.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { forkJoin, of } from 'rxjs'
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PushItService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  push(arr) {
    return of(arr).pipe(
      mergeMap(value => forkJoin(value.map(v => this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/random/' + v.id))))
    )
  }
}
```

I used this resource to write this code ... https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html ... see example 2

Have tested this and it works flawlessly but you should introduce some error handling. [This will help you too](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%203%3A16-18&version=NIV)

Comment: Thanks for your code sample but I think `of` will emit the whole array in one go not as a sequence of object?

Comment: it works, sends all requests at once, when all resolve then it logs, try it - if this not what you want then what do you want?